# Invalid KML file using Smart Map Plugin

Tags: craft3, plugin-smartmap, google-maps

I'm using Smart Map for Craft 3 to develop this filterable map for Columbia, Missouri. Here's the staging site:

http://visionzerodev.org/map-alpha/
This works brilliantly. Huzzah.

Now, I also need to add a couple of KML layers to it.

Here's where I'm developing the KML proof of concept:
http://visionzerodev.org/map-bravo/

BUT — I get the this error: "Invalid KML file".

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

The KML is importable in Google Maps:
(It was previously used as is in FusionTables)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J4epYVJPZXFrmQjq19PSfQuMiTGWmcbt&usp=sharing

The KML file is publicly accessible here:
http://visionzerodev.org/assets/data/high-crash-network.kml

Here's my Twig:

```
  {% set kmlFile = '/assets/data/high-crash-network.kml' %}

  {% set options = {
    height: 600,
  } %}

  {% if kmlFile %}
    {{ craft.smartMap.kml(kmlFile, options) }}
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like where you're going with this, but what you're trying to do isn't possible (yet).

As it currently stands, you need to use an **Asset** as the `kmlFile` parameter...

https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/kml-files/

It's on the roadmap to allow a string URL to be passed in directly.

---

**UPDATE:**

I've just added the ability to specify a KML by its absolute URL string. The new feature will be included in the next release of Smart Map. :)

Comment: For those that come after, I got this in the smartMap error log; 
smartMap.log("[smartmap-mapcanvas-1] Error: URL for KML file must be absolute.");</script></body>

I had to set my local asset url to include the base url